# button in vb application pressed itself every x of time in loop after first click

Tags: vb.net

this is my button and just need to know i very new to vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
```

Comment: Please read about read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Even a bad tutorial will cover this sort of getting started level question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to call a method in a button click, than to put the code in there - especially if you desire to perform a click "every x of time".

```
Dim timer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf doClickStuff)
Dim interval As Integer = 1000 ' 1000 ms = 1 second

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    doClickStuff()
End Sub

Private Sub doClickStuff()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf doClickStuff))
    Else
        ' do stuff here
        timer.Change(interval, -1)
    End If
End Sub

'' if you won't access UI elements in "do stuff here"
'' you can use this method which will run on a non-UI thread
'Private Sub doClickStuff()
'    ' do stuff here
'    timer.Change(interval, -1)
'End Sub

' stops the timer
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    timer.Change(-1, -1)
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you soo much it's worked perfectly with no error's thank you bro keep up